# Weird behaviour with Task Parallel Library Framework and Azure Instances

Tags: azure, task

I need some help solving a problem involving the Task Parallel Library with Azure instances. Below is code for my Worker Role.

Whenever I upload multiple files, a request is inserted into the queue and the worker process continously process queries Queues and gets the message. Once a message is retrieved, I do some long runnning process.  I used task schedulder so that mutliple request are served by multiple task instance on multiple instances.

Now the uestion is if one instance take a message from a queue and assigns the message to a task and it process, now i see another instance also retrieves the same message from Queue and process it.  Because of that my tasks are executed multiple times.

Please help me on this problem. My requirement is only one Azure instance of one Ccre handles one task operation not by mutliple by task.

```
public override void Run()
{
//Step1 : Get the message from Queue

//Step 2:  
Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                              //Message delete from Queue
                  PopulateBlobtoTable(uri, localStoragePath);

                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                                            throw;
                                        }
                                        finally
                                        {

                                        }
                                    }
                                    return "Finished!";                                    
                            })

                            catch (AggregateException ae)
                            {
                                foreach (var exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
                                {
                                    Trace.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using Windows Azure Storage queues, which have a default invisibility timeout of 90 seconds, when using the storage client APIs.  If your message is not completely processed and [explicitly deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758445.aspx) within that time period, it will reappear on the queue.

While you can increase this invisibility timeout to up to seven days when you [add the message to the queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh563575.aspx), you should be using operations that are [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent), meaning it doesn't matter if the message is processed multiple times.  It's your job to ensure idempotence, perhaps by recording a unique id (in table storage, SQL database, etc.) associated with each message and ignoring the message if you see it a second time and you find it's already been marked complete.

You might also look at [Windows Azure Queues and Windows Azure Service Bus Queues - Compared and Constrasted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx).  You'll note Service Bus queues have some additional constructs you can use to guarantee at-most-once (and at-least-once) delivery.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the uestion is if one instance take a message from a queue and assigns the message to a task and it process, now i see another instance also retrieves the same message from Queue and process it. Because of that my tasks are executed multiple times.

Are you getting the messages via "GET" semantics? If that's the case, then what's the visibility timeout you have set for your messages. When you "GET" a message, it should become invisible to other callers (read "instances" in your case) for a particular period of time which you can specify using visibility timeout period. Check out the documentation here for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758454.aspx